# Количество точек в Series

Tags: delphi

Какое свойство или какая функция в `Series` выводит количество точек в `Chart1.Series[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chart1.Series[0].Count`
из справки (TeeChart 2013):

> **TChartSeries.Count**
>   TChartSeries
>
> **function** Count: Integer;
>
> **Unit**
>   TeEngine
>
> **Description**
>   This function returns the number of points in the Series.